# Why is the empty set a subset of every set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Take for example the set $X=\{a, b\}$. I don't see $\emptyset$ anywhere in $X$, so how can it be a subset?

Comment: "Subset of" means something different than "element of". Note $\{a\}$ is also a subset of $X$, despite $\{ a \}$ not appearing "in" $X$.

Comment: Why does this question get a downvote?  It is not hard to see that someone can be asking this seriously.

Comment: Hint: Every element of the empty set is a pink elephant. Or an element of $X.$ (No joke)

Comment: I personally like @HagenvonEitzen's question `Or Can you name an element of ∅ that is not an element of X?`. If you think it like this, given ∅ and X, you can't really find an element of ∅ (nothing) that you don't find in X, and as a subset A is a just a set whose elements (every element) are included in another set B, that is you can't find an element in A which is not in B, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

that's because there are statements that are vacuously true. $Y\subseteq X$ means for all $y\in Y$, we have $y\in X$. Now is it true that for all $y\in \emptyset $, we have $y\in X$? Yes, the statement is vacuously true, since you can't pick any $y\in\emptyset$.

Answer (score 27):

Because every single element of $\emptyset$ is also an element of $X$. Or can you name an element of $\emptyset$ that is not an element of $X$?

Comment: But there are no elements in ∅, so how can every single element of ∅ be an element of X? You ask if we can name an element of ∅ that is not an element of X-- the answer is I can't, but conversely you can't name a single element of ∅ that IS an element of X. So how can we derive such a conclusion that the empty set is a subset of every set? It seems to me that the quality of being a sub-set cannot apply in this scenario because the definition assumes the existence of at least one element inside the set

Comment: @RandomUser [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Answer (score 21):

You must start from the definition :

> $Y \subseteq X$ iff $\forall x (x \in Y \rightarrow x \in X)$.

Then you "check" this definition with $\emptyset$ in place of $Y$ :

> $\emptyset \subseteq X$ iff $\forall x (x \in \emptyset \rightarrow x \in X)$.

Now you must use the truth-table definition of $\rightarrow$ ; you have that :

> "if $p$ is *false*, then $p \rightarrow q$ is *true*", for $q$ whatever;

so, due to the fact that :

> $x \in \emptyset$

is **not** *true*, for every $x$, the above truth-definition of $\rightarrow$ gives us that :

> "for all $x$, $x \in \emptyset \rightarrow x \in X$ is *true*", for $X$ whatever.

This is the reason why the *emptyset* ($\emptyset$) is a *subset* of every set $X$.

Comment: Shouldn't the last implication be "$\text{for all x, }x \in \emptyset \rightarrow x \in X$ is true"

Answer (score 4):

Subsets are not necessarily elements. The elements of $\{a,b\}$ are $a$ and $b$. But $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are different things.